# SSL v2 undefined symbol, Manjaro and Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssl

I'm going to report a problem quite complex.

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform python software. I'm on Manjaro Linux, which is an Arch-linux based distribution.

The software is packaged with cx_freeze, to facilitate its distribution. All the required libraries are bundled in the package, the user just has to execute a binary file to start the program. On Manjaro, the binary runs well.

However, when I try it on Ubuntu, I encounter a strange problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpinkmyph0/scripts/gui.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 969, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _load_unlocked(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 664, in _load_unlocked
    return _load_backward_compatible(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "/home/djipey/informatique/python/ChemBrows/my_twit.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 969, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    _call_with_frames_removed(import_, parent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 969, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _load_unlocked(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 664, in _load_unlocked
    return _load_backward_compatible(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twitter/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 969, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _load_unlocked(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 664, in _load_unlocked
    return _load_backward_compatible(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twitter/stream.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 969, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _load_unlocked(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 664, in _load_unlocked
    return _load_backward_compatible(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 969, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _load_unlocked(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 666, in _load_unlocked
    module = module_from_spec(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 577, in module_from_spec
    module = spec.loader.create_module(spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py", line 903, in create_module
    _imp.create_dynamic, spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
ImportError: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ChemBrows-0.9.6.linux-x86_64/ChemBrows-0.9.6.linux-x86_64/_ssl.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

After a bit of digging, it seems openssl is built without the support of version 2, on Ubuntu. What I don't understand, is why the program crashes: as all the libraries are packaged and delivered with my program, it shouldn't call any system libraries.

To summarize, I don't really understand why my program crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

After installing openssl with version 2 enabled on Ubuntu, it works perfectly. But the procedure is quite long and hard, I can't ask my future users to do it. So I should probably build python 3 without the support of ssl v2

Comment: "...as all the libraries are packaged and delivered with my program, it shouldn't call any system libraries..." - are you sure that OS libraries like libc, libssl etc are really included in what you ship, i.e. not only the python libraries? This would be very uncommon.

Comment: You're right, they are not, because patching openssl solved my problem. I'm still seeking a simpler solution though, for my users.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by uninstalling M2Crypto via pip, then installing the package python-m2crypto, and then to make sure install M2Crypto again

```
pip uninstall M2Crypto
apt-get install python-m2crypto
pip install M2Crypto
```

This solved for me